# PHP long running / zombie processes

Tags: php, supervisord

So we've got `supervisor` running a python 'director' process that's spawning php processes based on SQS stats. The PHP processes are are scraping websites.

Now in the recent years we've had no issues with these, but in the recent months what started happening was that some processes are just hanging after running for a while.

I've got some strace outputs:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fbe26b18d10}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fbe26b18d10}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {23227338, 293227395}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {23227338, 293432691}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {23227338, 293627011}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fbe26b18d10}, NULL, 8) = 0
select(11, [10], [], [], {1, 0})        = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {23227339, 295350994}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fbe26b18d10}, 8) = 0
```

These are just going around and around at the moment.

Ltrace shows that it's stuck in this loop:

```
memset(0x7fbe28e43b88, '\0', 8)                                                                               = 0x7fbe28e43b88
memset(0x7fbe28e43b60, '\0', 24)                                                                              = 0x7fbe28e43b60
memset(0x7fbe28e43b88, '\0', 8)                                                                               = 0x7fbe28e43b88
memset(0x7fbe28e43b60, '\0', 24)                                                                              = 0x7fbe28e43b60
memset(0x7fbe28e43b88, '\0', 8)                                                                               = 0x7fbe28e43b88
memset(0x7fbe28e43b60, '\0', 24)                                                                              = 0x7fbe28e43b60
```

Odd thing is that it's pretty much always happening whilst parsing content coming through from `http://xml.fxstreet.com/news/forex-news/index.xml`

Now before/while I start compiling php with debug and check out what's going on under the hood, I thought I'd ask what those calls are about, to see if anyone's got an idea.

Thanks

Comment: Is your PHP compiled with `--enable-sigchild`? `php-config --configure | grep sigchild` to check it out. It might be that the signal never reaches the supervisor. Have you tested whether supervisor reboots the processes that are explicitly killed?

Comment: Actually, sorry, let me be clear: supervisor is running a `python` process, that runs 1 or more php processes. In this case, this specific supervisor config's python lets the maximum 10 parallel php processes to run. As per the python's process manager's view, the processes are still running, and after a while it will use up all 10 slots and nothing will happen. All supervisord will see is a running python process. Eventually the issue is the same, from the 'outside' it looks like the php procs are not terminating.

Comment: And also, PHP is not compiled with --enable-debug or --enable-sigchild yet

Comment: Reckon there's no signal being sent from PHP as the processes are still cunning as per ps output

Comment: No worries, I'm using supervisor myself so I know it's python :) but the problem is like you said - the signal isn't reaching the parent (supervisor) process. This is usually happening when PHP is compiled with `--enable-sigchild` (or without, I'm without google capabilities at the time of writing this). Can you test whether supervisor is able to catch the signal emitted by php processes by creating a simple script that raises a signal after few seconds and then dies just to be 100% sure that it's not php compilation issue?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. So, our supervisor config is actually pointing to an in-house python executable called `director`, that's picking which parameters to use when invoking php processes based on AWS SQS queue lengths.

Comment: So which process is the parent process for php, `supervisord` or the inhouse `director` process?

Comment: The director process. I wouldn't suspect either the director or the supervisor, I was just wondering what sort of debugging / tracing tools there are available with the outputs given above.

Comment: So, just to get it clear - your supervisor starts another process called `director`, which in turn starts `n` PHP processes? Also, if you're interested in how to read the `strace` output - personally, I just read it as it is, then I google the specific functions I'm not familiar with (I know this doesn't help you whatsoever).

Comment: That's correct, supervisor -> director (python) -> php

Comment: Supervisor can't supervise processes that aren't it's **direct** child processes. However, this still doesn't explain why there's a zombie roaming around. You need to have supervisor start the php process, not director. Way around it would be that director uses SQS to do what it has to do, then it creates the config and tells supervisor to reload / start new php processes.